# ListView firing endReached itself, React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building an app in react native and I am using Lisview to display some data for some strange reason the endReached is triggered itself without me scrolling the listview and the listView ends up displaying all items at first like I have incremented page value each time, also i get duplicate results for first api call with value page 1.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, ListView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import categoryApi from './category.api';
import styles from './category.styles';
import CategoryItem from './category.items.component';
import ShopsNear from "../listshops/list-shops.component";

export default class Category extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rawData: [],
            isLoading: false,
            categories: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
            }),
            page: 1,
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: 'Categories',
        title: 'Categories',
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCategories();
    }

    fetchCategories() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        categoryApi.getOne(this.state.page).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.setState({
                    rawData: this.state.rawData.concat(response.data.data),
                    categories: this.state.categories.cloneWithRows(this.state.rawData.concat(response.data.data)),
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
                Alert.alert(
                    'Something wrong happened!',
                    'My Alert Msg',
                    [],
                    {cancelable: true}
                )
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    showMore = () => {
        this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1});
        console.log("End reached... page: " + this.state.page);
        this.fetchCategories();
    };

    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.projektiHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.projekti}>VALITSE PROJEKTI</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.categoriesList}>
                    <ListView
                        dataSource={this.state.categories}
                        renderRow={(rowData) => <CategoryItem navigate={navigate} item={rowData}/>}
                        renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator}/>}
                        onEndReached={this.showMore}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.shopsNear}>
                    <ShopsNear navigate={navigate}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Basically showMore() is itself, Anyone knows what's happening here?
I am trying to achieve so everytime I scroll and reaches the end of listview to call the showMore function which will fetch data from an API.

Answer (score 0):

check the onEndReachedThreshold props for listView component.

Comment: i dont see onEndReachedThreshold on documentaion, could u send me some references?